# Concatenate two tables by or

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables
One text has many-many items `writer`,`line`

`ttext_obj` table

```
test obj
1    text1
2    text2
3    text3
4    text4
```

`text_obj_writers` table

```
text writer
1    2
2    3
2    4
```

`text_obj_line` table

```
text line
1    2
4    3
1    4
```

So, I want to pick up the rows of `text_obj` which have at reast one `writer` or one `line`.

For now I made code like this .

The `text_obj` id which has at least one `write`

```
SELECT text.id  FROM `text_obj` text 
inner join text_obj_writers writer 
on writer.obj_id = text.id  group by text.id

//it returns
1
2
```

The `text_obj` id which have at least one `line`

```
SELECT text.id  FROM `text_obj` text 
inner join text_obj_lines line 
on line.obj_id = text.id  group by text.id

//it returns
1
4
```

But I want to take `or` of these

```
1
2
4
```

How can I concatenate two tables by or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select o.*
from text_obj o
where exists (select 1
              from text_obj_writers tow 
              where tow.obj_id = o.id
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from text_obj_lines tol 
              where tol.obj_id = o.id
             ) ;
```

This is much better than using aggregation, because you do not need to remove duplicates after joining the tables together.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `exists`:

```
select o.*
from ttext_obj o
where 
    exists (select 1 from text_obj_writers writer w where w.obj_id = o.id)
    or exists (select 1 from text_obj_lines l where l.obj_id = o.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `UNION` which will also remove duplicates:

```
select obj_id id from test_obj_writers
union
select obj_id id from test_obj_line
```

I assume that all `obj_id`s of both tables exist in the table `text_obj`.